# Adding elements in a row corresponding to a column

Tags: list

I'm extracting data from a CSV with 5 rows and 5 columns.

For example

```
print("Year  Age Scholarship Academic Stipend")
print("1982  20  $20000.00   $1000.00")
print("1983  21  $25000.00   NA")
print("1984  22  $30000.00   $500.00")
print("1982  20  $16000.00   $200.00")
print("1983  21  $17500.00   $600.00")
```

I extracted individual lists with all these elements:

```
Year = [1982,1983,1984,1982,1983]
Age = [20,21,22,20,21]
Scholarship = [20000, 25000, 30000, 16000, 17500]
Stipend_Amount = [1000, NA, 500, 200, 600]
```

I want to group all my years together.  How do I add the corresponding elements in column 4, corresponding only to the elements in Year?
For example.  I want to be able to print
    #Year     Total_Scholarship_Granted
    #1982     36000.00

But my for loop below is just adding all the elements together:

```
Start_Fund = 0
    for i in range(len(year)):
        Start_Fund += Scholarship[i]
        print(year[i],Start_Fund)
#1982  108500
```

I want my results to be:
1982  36000
(which is acquired by adding all amounts from 1982)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an if statement, to check if the year in the loop is the year you want (in your case 1982). So your pseydocode should look like this:

```
Start_Fund = 0
my_year=1982
for i in range(len(year)):
    if (year[i]==my_year)
        Start_Fund += Scholarship[i]
print(my_year,Start_Fund)
```